# Handlebars XML Parsing Errors in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, handlebars.js

I'm new to handlebars and just started implementing it into my solution. Everything is going well, but I'm getting errors in my console in Firefox only (Developer edition and normal). I'd like to start out by saying I'm writing HTML not XML.

`XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: http://127.0.0.5/templates/attachments.hbs?cacheBust=3
Line Number 5, Column 77:`

That is just one of many different errors I get. This one is due to the html entity `&nbsp;` Here's a screenshot of the reference Firefox makes (i assume it colors what it doesn't like in red).
[image: Firefox Image]

I am either fundamentally misunderstanding `{{#each}}` in handlebars, or something else is wrong. Like why is my template getting parsed as XML? 
Here is my template:

```
<div>
<table>
{{#each attachments}}
<tr>
    <td class="options-attachment-link"><i class="fa fa-paperclip">&nbsp;</i><a href="/api/upload/display_file?file={{this.internalName}}&amp;Id={{this.Id}}">{{this.customerName}}</a></td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
```

Here is my JS which handles the compilation of the handlebars:

```
var attachmentsPromise = $.get('/api/upload/get_attachments/id/'+Id);
var attachmentsTemplatePromise = $.get('/templates/attachments.hbs?cacheBust=3');
attachmentsPromise.done(function(attachmentsData){
    attachmentsTemplatePromise.done(function(attachmentTemplate){
        var template = Handlebars.compile(attachmentTemplate);
        var data = template({attachments: attachmentsData});
        $(myDiv).html(data);
    });
});
```

Just to note: everything works fine. For example, it still renders the `&nbsp;`. It's just the error in the firefox console
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
For anyone who may stumble upon this, I'm creating some new views by including ALL the handlebars templates in their own script tags once the view loads with type: `type="text/x-handlebars-template"`. Then I compile and render those on certain click events. I've included HTML entity characters `&equals;` in the script tag as well and am not longer getting any console errors. So maybe it had something to do with how AJAX was returning the data to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar scenario and found that the html response did not have the content type field in the header. Adding the content type as text/html fixed the issue
e.g.

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've also fixed this by modifying the file /etc/mime.types, by adding hbs to the end of the line beginning with text/plain.